# Extract string from string

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-way-to-parse-html-with-php)

I'm new to PHP and want to extract the second date from a string of this format :

```
<span class="date-display-start">28.12.2011</span><span class="date-display-separator"> - </span><span class="date-display-end">05.01.2012</span>
```

I'm not sure what PHP functions I can best use to do this ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a simple regular expression. Using the `DOMXPath` class or similar seems overkill, assuming you don't need more advanced data extraction than this.

```
preg_match('/<span class="date-display-end">(.*)<\/span>/U', $str, $result);
print array_pop($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in many different ways, the one of which is "`/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/`" regular expression:

```
<?php

$subject = '<span class="date-display-start">28.12.2011</span><span class="date-display-separator"> - </span><span class="date-display-end">05.01.2012</span>';

$regexp = '/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/';

preg_match_all($regexp, $subject, $matches);

print $matches[0][1];
```

The code above will print "`05.01.2012`", as in [this demo](http://ideone.com/E76qM).